# Javascript unfamiliar assignment construction

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sorry for basic question. I found the following construction in javascript and I not familiar with it. Do you know what is this construction?

I've changed the variables but the meaning is the same.

```
var pt = (
 5 in [1,2,3,5]?
 2:
 3 in [1,2,3]?
 1:
 7);
```

It looks like it checks all conditions and according to condition take an action, however the last step is without condition, something like this?

Comment: That makes no sense, same as `var pt = 7`

Comment: Does the new ECMA allow for `5 in [1,2,3,4,5]`?

Comment: @Andy In my tests, it seems that it works on Harmony. Is there a specific point of the new specs that you think should prevent it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This uses the [ternary conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and the [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). It could be written this way :

```
var pt;
if (5 in [1,2,3,5]) { // is there an element with index 5 ?
   pt = 2;
} else if (3 in [1,2,3]) {
   pt = 1;
} else {
   pt = 7;
}
```

But this looks more like a puzzle than like a legitimate code. This especially looks like a trap :

```
5 in [1,2,3,5]
```

Most coders wouldn't take it for what it is : the test of the presence of 5 **as a key** (see [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)). So it's `false` (but `3 in [1,2,3,5]` would be `true`).

The whole is equivalent to

```
var pt = 7;
```

Comment: Right about the key thing. But just a small error: `4 in [1,2,3,5]` would be `false` (index is 0-based) `3 in [1,2,4,5]` would be `true`.

Comment: @BaliBalo Yes, I've read the array too fast, I've read it as `4 in [1,2,3,4,5]`... But there was no `4`... Just like Andy in another comment, I see...

Comment: I cancelled it after your comment. It just seems a really bad way of testing for length. I guess if it was an array of strings it might have been easier to parse. I won't be using it any time soon. Nice answer btw.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with a few more parenthesis you'll understand better.

```
var pt = (5 in [1,2,3,5]) ? 2 : ((3 in [1,2,3]) ? 1 : 7);
```

So it's basiqually a sequence of ternary conditions. It is equivalent to:

```
var pt;
if(5 in [1,2,3,5])
    pt = 2;
else if(3 in [1,2,3])
    pt = 1;
else
    pt = 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

That code is extremely poorly formatted, but expanded out it translates to:

```
var pt;
if( 5 in [1,2,3,5]) pt = 2;
else if( 3 in [1,2,3]) pt = 1;
else pt = 7;
```

It's just a ternary operator written in a horribly deformed way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a conditional assignment that works as follows:

`var pt =`

`if 5 is in [1,2,3,5]` `pt=2`

`else if 3 in [1,2,3]` `pt=1`

`else pt=7`

Note the [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) checks if a given key is in a object and not whether the value exists so `5 in [1,2,3,5]` is false but `0 in [1,2,3,5]` is true

Answer (score 0):

Writing it

```
var pt = (5 in [1,2,3,5]?2:(3 in [1,2,3]?1:7));
```

makes it more clear.

This often comes from the first number (5) being put into a template via a server-sided script, but the if .. then logic being processed in JS. Ugly, but works well.